# Using unsignedByte with base64 encoding

Tags: delphi, soap

I have made a SOAP API using WSDL, and I need to transfer bytes of a file from client to the server of the API. I am using `unsignedBinary[]` array type in the WSDL to describe the data to be passed. The WSDL description is as follows:

```
<complexType name="TByteArray">

<complexContent>

<restriction base="soapenc:Array">

<sequence/>

<attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" n1:arrayType="xs:unsignedByte[]" xmlns:n1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>

</restriction>

</complexContent>

</complexType>
```

I am trying to send the data in raw bytes, which is giving error.
Now I am doing a base64 encode while sending the binary data using the soap API call.
It works fine if I send the data using PHP Client, but it is not working when I use a Delphi application to send the data.

Do you think that converting the binary data to base64 is making the Delphi application not allow to send the data?
`unsignedByes` is not allowed to transfer to Base 64? Does anyone know the details of this?

Comment: It would be more useful if you posted your working php code and your broken delphi code this way people can point out the differences for you.

Comment: Do you need to use unsignedByte for this? Personally I usually just send base64 encoded data as ordinary string values in the SOAP message, pick it up on the server side, and decode it back to it's original binary value. I don't know how this would work in PHP, but it certainly works fine in a Delphi/Java environment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you valuable comments, but i have solved this problem.
I removed the following code and transferred the binary on the "type:xs:hexbinary"

`<part name="abData" type="xs:hexBinary"/>`

and it works like magic.
It converts the binary automatically to hex and on receiving on the server it again converts to binary on it's own...

Thanks.